# Click event is not fired when vertical scroll position changed in focusin event using jQuery.scrollTop()

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I am facing an issue with jQuery scrollTop. Please check the code below. When I click on the button first time, click event is not getting fired. Is there any way to overcome this issue ? In IE it is working fine. I have this in chrome.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#goTop').on('focusin',function(){
    $('body').scrollTop('0');
  })
  $('#goTop').on('click',function(){
    alert('clicked');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc in dolor lectus. Vestibulum facilisis aliquet bibendum. Aliquam vestibulum ullamcorper elit interdum accumsan. Aenean consectetur placerat pulvinar. Integer id libero vel odio mollis lobortis
  sed semper turpis. Ut at velit et mi faucibus egestas. Curabitur sed ultrices libero. Sed efficitur ex eu posuere congue. Pellentesque non gravida tellus. Sed ut fringilla nunc. Suspendisse sit amet fringilla purus. Vestibulum id augue mi. Suspendisse
  felis elit, porta vel varius eget, mattis vitae felis. Proin interdum scelerisque blandit. Vestibulum eget massa eget ex congue pulvinar. Aliquam vulputate congue ante quis euismod. Nulla sit amet sapien nec odio placerat varius. Etiam varius pulvinar
  risus, ac dignissim ligula. Fusce enim urna, ultricies id euismod nec, lacinia ac ante. Phasellus a nisi vestibulum nisi pretium sollicitudin. Aliquam sit amet ligula ex. Nam egestas ac mauris id mattis. Maecenas bibendum quam non nibh porta mollis.
  Ut laoreet mi elit, a pulvinar quam auctor eget. Phasellus sit amet pulvinar diam. Praesent sed nisl justo. Curabitur facilisis justo ut enim placerat consectetur. Integer odio ligula, venenatis ac tempor id, bibendum eu turpis. Donec laoreet, risus
  sit amet commodo feugiat, turpis ex venenatis arcu, ultricies tincidunt felis diam at tortor. Suspendisse dictum lorem ligula. Ut tristique consequat quam, in fringilla nibh porta at. Maecenas sit amet neque ut ex molestie congue. Nam sed sagittis nisl.
  Ut lobortis arcu quis arcu facilisis, ac maximus ex dignissim. Proin id lobortis massa, sed mollis eros. Curabitur tristique aliquam pretium. In imperdiet fringilla suscipit. Donec imperdiet mauris molestie, laoreet urna sed, pellentesque libero. Ut
  aliquet a tellus in rhoncus. Vivamus non ultrices erat. Aenean sed scelerisque nibh, vitae sagittis dolor. Praesent quis neque risus. Suspendisse vitae nisl lacinia, sagittis nibh a, molestie orci. Suspendisse eu aliquet ante. Cras in erat porta, condimentum
  nisl id, tempus odio. Nullam ut ante feugiat, molestie erat ut, ultrices augue. Mauris mattis fermentum tincidunt. Fusce vel euismod dui. Quisque non lobortis quam. Pellentesque massa elit, scelerisque a lacus eget, consequat congue ligula. Fusce hendrerit
  aliquet arcu at ultrices. Aliquam faucibus nunc vel imperdiet auctor. Maecenas quis fringilla turpis. Nulla venenatis neque massa, ut sagittis augue finibus in. Aenean felis odio, mollis in consequat vel, porta eu neque. Donec elementum mollis neque,
  vitae luctus risus molestie nec. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Integer arcu leo, congue et neque at, tempus imperdiet mauris. Vestibulum eros ligula, laoreet non enim nec, viverra vestibulum augue.
  Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam nec fringilla turpis. Fusce lobortis nunc ac ligula vulputate, quis rhoncus mi dapibus. In non pharetra nibh, non tempus ex. Phasellus non lorem non justo ornare ultricies. Cras turpis diam, malesuada in neque in, ultricies
  iaculis quam. Mauris tempus est ut mauris facilisis ultricies. Vivamus mollis mi sed nulla sodales, id pellentesque ante consequat. Mauris facilisis id felis ac viverra. Nulla cursus pellentesque volutpat. Aenean et elit in lectus elementum ullamcorper.
  Donec feugiat interdum odio, vel vulputate ipsum pellentesque at. Praesent at eros massa. Vivamus sapien diam, hendrerit non risus ac, sollicitudin volutpat augue. Donec non pharetra turpis, a venenatis sem. In consectetur vitae magna a vestibulum.
  Ut lacinia aliquet sagittis.
</div>

<input type='button' id='goTop'value='Go Top' />
```

Comment: why are you using focusin ??

Comment: Actually in my application there is a sticky footer. So when ever focus comes to textbox or button I have to move it above footer.

Comment: Why you do two separate functions for same element when you can make it do what you want in one function ?

Comment: The one which i have given here is a sample. Actually the focus event is generic for all the textbox and buttons. But the click event is specific

Comment: @Jithu P Rajan  Then write a function for textbox with focusin event to only change scroll position to top and one for button to also do that + alert message. Your javascript code runs in cascade order. If you attribued two different events for same element, the one which will trigger will be the one you writed first.

Comment: @EddNewGate : 'If you attribued two different events for same element, the one which will trigger will be the one you writed first' - I dont think so. If I remove the scrollTop('0'), both will execute.

Comment: @JithuPRajan "If I remove the `scrollTop('0')`, both will execute" . You said you removed one command. How can "both" execute when you have only one left, that being the `alert()` command?

Comment: I said if I remove only the $('body').scrollTop('0') line then both focusin and click event will work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `mousedown` event, instead of `click`, it seems a bug on Chrome browser, with Firefox I get the alert message but not the scroll effect. However I'd choose a different solution, like follow:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#goTop').on('focusin',function(){
    $('body').scrollTop('0');
  })
  $('#goTop').on('mousedown',function(){
    alert('clicked');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc in dolor lectus. Vestibulum facilisis aliquet bibendum. Aliquam vestibulum ullamcorper elit interdum accumsan. Aenean consectetur placerat pulvinar. Integer id libero vel odio mollis lobortis
  sed semper turpis. Ut at velit et mi faucibus egestas. Curabitur sed ultrices libero. Sed efficitur ex eu posuere congue. Pellentesque non gravida tellus. Sed ut fringilla nunc. Suspendisse sit amet fringilla purus. Vestibulum id augue mi. Suspendisse
  felis elit, porta vel varius eget, mattis vitae felis. Proin interdum scelerisque blandit. Vestibulum eget massa eget ex congue pulvinar. Aliquam vulputate congue ante quis euismod. Nulla sit amet sapien nec odio placerat varius. Etiam varius pulvinar
  risus, ac dignissim ligula. Fusce enim urna, ultricies id euismod nec, lacinia ac ante. Phasellus a nisi vestibulum nisi pretium sollicitudin. Aliquam sit amet ligula ex. Nam egestas ac mauris id mattis. Maecenas bibendum quam non nibh porta mollis.
  Ut laoreet mi elit, a pulvinar quam auctor eget. Phasellus sit amet pulvinar diam. Praesent sed nisl justo. Curabitur facilisis justo ut enim placerat consectetur. Integer odio ligula, venenatis ac tempor id, bibendum eu turpis. Donec laoreet, risus
  sit amet commodo feugiat, turpis ex venenatis arcu, ultricies tincidunt felis diam at tortor. Suspendisse dictum lorem ligula. Ut tristique consequat quam, in fringilla nibh porta at. Maecenas sit amet neque ut ex molestie congue. Nam sed sagittis nisl.
  Ut lobortis arcu quis arcu facilisis, ac maximus ex dignissim. Proin id lobortis massa, sed mollis eros. Curabitur tristique aliquam pretium. In imperdiet fringilla suscipit. Donec imperdiet mauris molestie, laoreet urna sed, pellentesque libero. Ut
  aliquet a tellus in rhoncus. Vivamus non ultrices erat. Aenean sed scelerisque nibh, vitae sagittis dolor. Praesent quis neque risus. Suspendisse vitae nisl lacinia, sagittis nibh a, molestie orci. Suspendisse eu aliquet ante. Cras in erat porta, condimentum
  nisl id, tempus odio. Nullam ut ante feugiat, molestie erat ut, ultrices augue. Mauris mattis fermentum tincidunt. Fusce vel euismod dui. Quisque non lobortis quam. Pellentesque massa elit, scelerisque a lacus eget, consequat congue ligula. Fusce hendrerit
  aliquet arcu at ultrices. Aliquam faucibus nunc vel imperdiet auctor. Maecenas quis fringilla turpis. Nulla venenatis neque massa, ut sagittis augue finibus in. Aenean felis odio, mollis in consequat vel, porta eu neque. Donec elementum mollis neque,
  vitae luctus risus molestie nec. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Integer arcu leo, congue et neque at, tempus imperdiet mauris. Vestibulum eros ligula, laoreet non enim nec, viverra vestibulum augue.
  Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam nec fringilla turpis. Fusce lobortis nunc ac ligula vulputate, quis rhoncus mi dapibus. In non pharetra nibh, non tempus ex. Phasellus non lorem non justo ornare ultricies. Cras turpis diam, malesuada in neque in, ultricies
  iaculis quam. Mauris tempus est ut mauris facilisis ultricies. Vivamus mollis mi sed nulla sodales, id pellentesque ante consequat. Mauris facilisis id felis ac viverra. Nulla cursus pellentesque volutpat. Aenean et elit in lectus elementum ullamcorper.
  Donec feugiat interdum odio, vel vulputate ipsum pellentesque at. Praesent at eros massa. Vivamus sapien diam, hendrerit non risus ac, sollicitudin volutpat augue. Donec non pharetra turpis, a venenatis sem. In consectetur vitae magna a vestibulum.
  Ut lacinia aliquet sagittis.
</div>

<input type='button' id='goTop'value='Go Top' />
```

Comment: This looks an alternative. I believe this is working because mousedown is triggered before focusin event. But mousedown will not be triggered on enter key press. Then again I have to write listener for keypress :(